# How to programatically install JRE(Java Runtime Environment) and setup class paths using C/C++ code?

Tags: java, c++, java-8, classpath

**My Question**

- I have developed a java desktop software which I wish to distribute to lay users
- Java jars require a JRE and proper classpath to run and I can not expect the lay user to actually setup the classpaths at his/her system
- I think if I can provide compiled executable C++ program : it would run on most of the systems without any extra effort
- Therefore I wish to write a C/C++ program which could check for **JRE** , then download and install the latest JRE and ALSO setup the **classpaths** for the user
- When this has been done, my Java installer would take over.
- How can that be done in C++ ?(**ESPECIALLY the class path setup** for **macos** and **windows**)

Comment: so you basically want to embed a `jre` with your software?

Comment: @Eugene Yes Sir, I just want to do that but this is the first time i would be distributing an application and as such I have no knowledge of how the launch4j works

Comment: basically All I would want is that the Java Installer Jar file MUST get executed on a system(macos/windows) without the JRE installed.

Comment: I understood that, we do that too - embed the jre into our product, even if I have not worked on this directly; so this is decently doable, but we do it with maven...

Comment: Yes, I am looking at a multi platform install4j ...I will update here

Comment: Use one of the free/commercial install package builders.  You don't need C++ for this task.

Comment: What is the task of the install4j , does embeding JRE mean  that the application would run without classpath setup or that the system need not have JRE pre installed alltogether?(because I just tested the install4j which upon the launch of the created .exe file asked me to locate the JRE)